# Retrieve rows from a database table (query error)

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database with a table `book` (`id, name, display, priority`)

For example:

```
 ________________________________________________________
|    id    |    name    |    display    |    priority    |
 --------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |    test1   |     True      |       5        |
|    2     |    test2   |     True      |       3        |
|    3     |    test3   |     False     |       4        |
|    4     |    test4   |     True      |       1        |
|    5     |    test5   |     True      |       2        |
|    6     |    test6   |     False     |       1        |
|    7     |    test7   |     True      |       1        |
|    8     |    test8   |     True      |       4        |
|    9     |    test9   |     True      |       3        |
|    10    |    test10  |     False     |       2        |
|    11    |    test11  |     True      |       3        |
|    12    |    test12  |     True      |       5        |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to write a query to get only 3 rows with priority 1 and 2 and 3 and display is true

I use this stored procedure to display books that have priority 1 and 2 and 3 (the most specific books)

**Problem**:

1. when I try to `select top 3 order by priority` then the query get the first 3 rows with priority = 1, while I need 1-record with priority = 1 and 1-record with priority = 2 and 1-record with priority = 3.
2. when I try to get `distinct book`, distinct works over all records not on priority only

**Result:**

I need the result to be like:

```
 ________________________________________________________
|    id    |    name    |    display    |    priority    |
 --------------------------------------------------------
|    4     |    test4   |     True      |       1        |
|    2     |    test2   |     True      |       3        |
|    5     |    test5   |     True      |       2        |
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do that?

thanks for help

Comment: i am working with sql server 2008 r2

Comment: *within* a priority, how do we decide which row to retrieve - we (and SQL Server) need you to define an actual rule we can follow. It's not "the one with the lowest `id` value", since you selected `id` 9 for `priority` 3, rather than `id` 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
with cte as (
     select *,row_number() over(partition by priority  order by id) as row_num
     from book
     where  display='true'
     and priority in (1,2,3)
     )
select id,name,display,priority
from   cte 
where  row_num=1
```

Comment: please if you can explain this query? what i understand that you ceate a view and then you get info from it. what `over` means? and what is `partition`?

Comment: That may select rows with priorities 4 or 5, and even if it does pick the ones for priorities 1, 2 and 3, it will select the row with `id` 2, not 9, for priority 3.

Comment: i set above an example, i need query to get 3 records. (the first one is the first row query found with priority 1 or 2 or 3 with display = true) (the second one is the second row query found with priority 1 or 2 or 3 with display = true)(the third one is the third row query found with priority 1 or 2 or 3 with display = true)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Good point, I have corrected my answer as per the first part of your comment, and regarding the second part, the question(not your question, the question posted) is not clear about that...

Comment: I see the question has been updated to use `id` 2, not 9 now. I'd be happier if the OP would actually articulate the rule though - i.e. it now *appears* to be "lowest `id` value within each priority"

Comment: @danny-london: I have used the row_number function in sql server. Please see examples in http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/